# AngularJS : ng-bind-html depending on variable

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, data-binding

I want to display some html on a scene (an image of a man or a woman), depending on the gender of the person logged on my website. The directive ng-bind-html works when I define "imageToLoad" statically. However, it doesn't work if my html to bind is defined by a function.

The console tells me: *TypeError: $scope.getHtml is not a function*

Here is my simplified code:

HTML:

```
<div id="img-container" ng-controller="sceneCtrl" ng-bind-html="imgToLoad">
</div>
```

JS:

```
.controller('sceneCtrl', function($scope, $http, $sce){
    /* This works
    ** $scope.imgToLoad = $sce.trustAsHtml('<img id="over2" src="imgMale.png"/>');
    */

    $scope.imgToLoad=$scope.getHtml();

    $scope.getHtml=function(){

      var gender='male';
      if(gender=='male'){
        return $sce.trustAsHtml('<img id="over2" src="imgMale.png"/>');
      }
      else if(gender=='female'){
        return $sce.trustAsHtml('<img id="over2" src="imgFemale.png"/>');
      }
      return 'error getHtml';
    }
})
```

I simplified the JS with a variable saying the gender, but eventually the gender will be given by the backend, from a database.

According to my research, I may have to use "compile", but I have no idea how this works.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Did you get any error?

Comment: Try putting function definition before the following line: $scope.imgToLoad=$scope.getHtml();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that you are calling `$scope.getHtml` before you initialised it so at the time you call the value is undefined.

Don't put functions into `$scope` unless you need them there, and don't call them through `$scope` from javascript when you can call them directly. This should work:

```
.controller('sceneCtrl', function($scope, $http, $sce){

    $scope.imgToLoad = getHtml();

    function getHtml(){

      var gender='male';
      if(gender=='male'){
        return $sce.trustAsHtml('<img id="over2" src="imgMale.png"/>');
      }
      else if(gender=='female'){
        return $sce.trustAsHtml('<img id="over2" src="imgFemale.png"/>');
      }
      return 'error getHtml';
    }
})
```

Comment: This solution works perfectly, thank you very much. I'm new to AngularJS so I thought it was mandatory to declare the functions into $scope for it to work properly.

Comment: Note that someone tried to edit this answer to move the function to the top because that is their preferred style. That would have been better as a comment rather than an edit so I rejected it. Two problems: I try to make answers match the style of the question where there's no real reason to change, and I also prefer myself to put function after all the executable code in the controller body. Also see angular style guide https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#style-y034

Answer (score 0):

Use custom directive ng-html

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/AntonWebDev2012/mb4nv5my/

```
.directive('ngHtml', [ '$compile', function ($compile) {
    return function (scope, elem, attrs) {
      if (attrs.ngHtml) {
        elem.html(scope.$eval(attrs.ngHtml));
        $compile(elem.contents())(scope);
      }
      scope.$watch(attrs.ngHtml, function (newValue, oldValue) {
        if (newValue && newValue !== oldValue) {
          elem.html(newValue);
          $compile(elem.contents())(scope);
        }
      });
    };
  } ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Direct html worked, So the problem is : function is called before it is initialized, try calling it after.
Eg.
`$scope.getHtml=function(){
 }
$scope.imgToLoad=$scope.getHtml();`

Answer (score 0):

Here My Code..  I made some changes..

```
.controller('sceneCtrl',['$scope','$http','$sce', function($scope, $http, $sce) {

var gender='male';
$scope.getHtml=function(){
  if(gender=='male'){
    return $sce.trustAsHtml('<h3>Pablo</h3><img id="over2" src="http://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/male-icon-19.png"/>');
  }
  else if(gender=='female'){
    return $sce.trustAsHtml('<h3>Picaso</h3><img id="over2" src="http://weknowyourdreams.com/images/female/female-01.jpg"/>');
  }
  return 'error getHtml';
}; 
 $scope.imgToLoad = $scope.getHtml();


 }]);

})(window.angular);
```

First I Declare the getHTML function and then call it.